# Background style doesn't show up on Progress Bar

Tags: android

I'm trying to do something like this:

[image]

This is what my code does:

[image]

I've this code in my drawable file:

**progress_bar_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape
            android:innerRadius="70dp"
            android:shape="ring"
            android:thickness="18dp">
        </shape>
    </item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="70dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="18dp">

        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ff0f315f"
            android:startColor="#ff005563"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</item>


<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="70dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="18dp">

        <gradient
            android:endColor="#ff1490e4"
            android:startColor="#ff00c0dd"
            android:type="sweep" />
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

**layout:**

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/bar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="99"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar_layout"
        android:secondaryProgress="30" />
```

The problem is that my background style doesn't show up. That's why i'm using progress to do background's job, but as you can see, it doesn't work pretty well bcs the maximum size is 99, and there's a space in the end. Am i missing some code?

Comment: Can you upload image of what you are trying to achieve , It can be easily made in Ms paint or photoshop

Comment: @L-X already available.

Comment: If you just want black background behind progressBar just set this android:background="#222222" in your <progressBar > tag it will do the trick

Comment: @L-X i'm not talking about layout background, but progress bar background. The blue part of the progress bar should be my background, but i'm using the progress to pretend that its my background.

Comment: Sorry I still can't figure out what you want , The image that you have shown is what your code is outputing (IF i am not wrong) show one more image thats shows what effect you want or vice-versa so we can compare what is missing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, i had to split **progress_bar_layout.xml** drawable file for each element, so, one file with the progress settings, and another for background settings.
And then, i added them to the respective elements.

```
 android:background="@drawable/circle_shape"
 android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
```

Using layer list, the project didn't find the background setting, so this approach solved my problem.

**circle_shape.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:innerRadius="60dp"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:thickness="10dp"
    android:useLevel="false">

    <solid android:color="@color/blue"></solid>

</shape>
```

**circular_progress_bar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="270"
    android:toDegrees="270">
    <shape
        android:innerRadius="60dp"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thickness="10dp"
        android:useLevel="true">

        <solid android:color="@color/blue"></solid>

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

Comment: Can you update your answer with code of circle_shape.xml and circular_progress_bar.xml , I want to see how you solved it